# Uso dell'espressione "è un cane"

Tags: word-meaning, translation

"Lui **è talmente un cane**, come ciclista, che anche vuole correre non riesce [...]"

Cosa significa questa espressione? Non sono riuscita a trovare niente sui dizionari o su Internet. Mi potresti aiutare?

Grazie!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Da [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cane1/):

> Frequente con valore spreg., per indicare un uomo di animo cattivo,
>   spietato, oppure inabile, incapace nel lavoro che fa: quel c. di
>   aguzzino; lavoro fatto da cane (o più spesso da cani), di pessima
>   fattura; un c., cantante o attore di teatro inadatto alla scena per
>   irrimediabile insufficienza di qualità e di mezzi.

Nel caso da te riportato sicuramente viene sottolineata l'incapacità del soggetto come ciclista e di conseguenza le sue scarse prestazioni sportive.

Answer (score 2):

"Guidare come un cane" vuol dire essenzialmente guidar male, senza badare troppo alle regole.